# How to make objects appear when hovering over image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, navigation, hover

I have a problem. I'm trying to edit my code in Wordpress and running into a problem. I want to make objects (left/right navigation) appear when hovering over the slider image. See website here: pxljar.com/word

So basically, the left/right navigation arrows should only be visible when hovering over the image on the slider.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code you are working on please.

Comment: hidde the arrows and show them with the onmouseover event, thats the best help i can give you with the info you've given

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS only :

in your css

add

> ul.flex-direction-nav {display:none}

here we hide the navigation bar

add

> ul.slides:hover + ul.flex-direction-nav {
>   display: block;
>   }

this will show the navigation buttons only when you hover over the slides